# delphi fastreport - adding multiple data on a desired location

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is it possible to add multiple data anywhere on the fastreport page? The only thing I know that can add multiple data is the Master detail, but it is impossible to resize nor move it. I made a format where the data's should be located there.

Answer (score 0):

You may set Engine.CurY, Engine.CurX in the TfrxMasterData.OnBeforePrint event

Comment: i dont have that event in my fastreport. Is there any option?

Comment: You may use TfrxReport.OnBeforePrint
`if Sender.Name = 'MasterData1' then frxReport1.Engine.CurY := 100;`

Comment: but i cant see tfrxreport.OnBeforePrint on my event option.

Comment: @user3505049: The FastReport User Guide (on your FastReports Start menu) has an example of using OnBeforePrint, under the heading *Script->Example of Using the "OnBeforePrint" Event*.

Comment: TfrxReport.OnBeforePrint available in the Delphi. Free FR Embarcadero Edition doesn't supports scripts

Comment: i've already did that but nothings change. whats the purpose of doing that by the way?

Comment: Create a small demo project and send it to support@fast-report.com